# Predictive-Web: How to track on SKU-level?

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics, einstein, einstein-recommendations

i am here to ask a simple question:
**How is it possible to track on sku level?** Or to rephrase it: **How can i track articles?**

When it comes to tracking on productcode level you can use this code:

```
<script>
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID-Number"]);
  _etmc.push(["trackPageView",{ "item" : "INSERT_PRODUCT_CODE" }]); 
</script>
```

**Which code do i have to use to track articles?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rick Thomas of Salesforce, (I believe he is a product owner of predictive web or something similar):

> If your catalog mapping has both a ProductCode and SkuID, it is not
>   possible to track item views at the sku level.
>
> One possible workaround is to map your catalog without a product code
>   - in this case the sku serves as both the sku and the product code. However, depending on your use case, you'd likely find that the
>   recommendations contain multiple skus sharing the same product code.